# evading the use of if statements: shortening the code

Tags: ruby

I watched the video at https://gorails.com/blog/refactoring-if-statements but was looking for a more concise way of evading the use of multiple if or case statements.
The following works

```
            def process(input)
                commands = {
                    :q => Proc.new { puts "Goodbye" }, 
                    :tweet => Proc.new { puts "tweeting" }, 
                    :dm => Proc.new { puts "direct messaging"}, 
                    :help => Proc.new { puts "helping"}
                }
                commands[input.to_sym].call
            end

            process "tweet"
```

But how could i further shorten this ? I tried the following

```
            def process(input)
                commands = {
                    :q => { puts "Goodbye" }, 
                    :tweet => { puts "tweeting" }, 
                    :dm => { puts "direct messaging"}, 
                    :help => { puts "helping"}
                }
                commands[input.to_sym].to_proc.call
            end

            process "tweet"
```

but then i get the error

```
            # syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
            #       :q => { puts "Goodbye" }, 
            #                     ^
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: if you want to get rid of Proc.new you could either use a lambda (stabby lambda syntax: `-> {puts "goodbye"}`) or use the proc method `proc {puts "goodbye"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [lambda](http://makandracards.com/makandra/17305-short-lambda-syntax-in-ruby-1-9) syntax

```
def process(input)
  commands = {
    :q => ->{ puts "Goodbye" }, 
    :tweet => ->{ puts "tweeting" }, 
    :dm => ->{ puts "direct messaging"}, 
    :help => ->{ puts "helping"}
  }
  commands[input.to_sym].to_proc.call
end

process "tweet"
```

Using the new Hash syntax can shorten this further:

```
def process(input)
  {
    q: ->{ puts "Goodbye" }, 
    tweet: ->{ puts "tweeting" }, 
    dm: ->{ puts "direct messaging"}, 
    help: ->{ puts "helping"}
  }[input.to_sym].call
end

process "tweet"
```

Comment: `lambda` and `proc` not the same.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen Correct, but they serve the same ends in this use case - "evading the use of if statements"

Comment: that's nice, didn't know of this lambda syntax

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Kernel#proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-proc):

> Equivalent to Proc.new

```
def process(input)
  commands = {
    :q => proc { puts "Goodbye" }, 
    :tweet => proc { puts "tweeting" }, 
    :dm => proc { puts "direct messaging"}, 
    :help => proc { puts "helping"}
  }[input.to_sym].call
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether what you suggest or I will suggest here improves the elegance or the readability of the code under question but you could shorten it even further by using the hash accessor pattern as in:

```
def process(input)
  commands = {
    :q => Proc.new { puts "Goodbye" }, 
    :tweet => Proc.new { puts "tweeting" }, 
    :dm => Proc.new { puts "direct messaging"}, 
    :help => Proc.new { puts "helping"}
  }[input.to_sym].call
end
```